# Dealing with repeated fields

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm storing a log on the server with multiple lists where I store some data such as dates and information associated to these dates. The first field of the first list corresponds to the first field of the rest, the second field of the first list to the second field, and so on.

Using the FLATTEN function I managed to show this information, but it shows a combination of the whole data on the lists. Having 4 lists 3 fields each, generates 12 different rows.

Is there any way to show only three results, by order on the lists?

Comment: Can you make put a sample of the data on a public dataset? Probably instead of having multiple repeated fields, you could have one repeated record with all these fields (then you wouldn't have this problem when flattening).

Comment: Is the link working?

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/egolike.com:egolike-production:egotest.egoViews

Many thanks :-)

Comment: link works, partial solution upcoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't love this solution, but it's the first idea that comes to mind that solves your problem:

```
SELECT dates, lead, userID FROM 
 (SELECT NTH(1, dates) WITHIN RECORD dates, NTH(1, lead) WITHIN RECORD lead, userID
  FROM [egolike.com:egolike-production:egotest.egoViews]),
 (SELECT NTH(2, dates) WITHIN RECORD dates, NTH(2, lead) WITHIN RECORD lead, userID
  FROM [egolike.com:egolike-production:egotest.egoViews]),
 (SELECT NTH(3, dates) WITHIN RECORD dates, NTH(3, lead) WITHIN RECORD lead, userID
  FROM [egolike.com:egolike-production:egotest.egoViews])
WHERE dates IS NOT NULL
```

Basically we are mapping the Nth value of a column within a record to the Nth value of the other column. A drawback is the need of explicitly calling each Nth place by number. Hopefully you can re-import the data with a different structure! (One repeated column, containing the aligned records)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked but you're right, I should think on a better structure.

Comment: I'm thinking about a different structure, where for every pair of userID and egolikeID I save a repeated record to store the date, lead, fromView and leadType, but I have no idea about how to store this kind of structure on Google App Engine. How can it be done?

Comment: in Python ndb there are structured properties: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

Comment: We're programming on Java, we have no idea how to create this structure.

Comment: mmmh... I would ask that as a separate question with the [google-app-engine] tag. I'm more fluent with the Python side of the cloud.